# How can I replace shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I am new to WordPress. I am trying to create a plugin. I'm using a static shortcode:

`[SRPMGT id=12345]`

And this shortcode can be placed in any page. I want to replace this shortcode with html content:

`<div class="result"> Content to replace... </div>`

Note: This shortcode can be placed in any page.

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API will get you started on the correct path, it also has example's.

Comment: `<div class="result"> <?php echo do_shortcode('[SRPMGT id=12345]');?></div>`.

Comment: @Anand I have already passed through that documentation but I did nt understand any thing. Can u help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[function add_shortcode( $tag, $func )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

is the core of what you need to know.

So insert into your functions.php:

> function srpmgt_shortcode() {
>       return ' Content to replace... '; }
>
> add_shortcode('SRPMGT_id=12345', 'srpmgt_shortcode');

Comment: hey I heard plugins does not make any changes to other codes. Is its the correct way to do this?

Comment: Thanks its was the answer I didnt had a functions.php file inside plugin. I have added this code in plugin's starting page then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to functions.php file of your plugin

```
// [srpgmt id="id-value"]
function srpgmt_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 'something',        
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<div class="result"> Content to replace... </div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'srpgmt', 'srpgmt_func' );
```

As already mentioned in the comment, for further reading go to : http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API